# How can I get the Clickable "id" for the "thumbs up" used in messenger?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm not able to use **.click()** method while using the title id of "thumbs-up" in the messenger. There was a path given inside the tag.

I just want to know **how I can click over the thumbs up.**

I also tried it with SVG class. But it was also showing "null" or not clickable.

I have used this method to like facebook images. I was able to get the right id of it. But now I am confused in the SVG part of the thumbsUP section.

```
var thumb=document.getElementsById('js_sf'); 
for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
    thumb[i].click();
}
```

I was expecting that using this method "2 thumbs ups" would be sent. But now its showing "can not read property click.

Answer (score 0):

first of all `document.getElementsById` is not a thing. An ID is unique, so it'll be `document.getElementById`

Try `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.getElementsByTagName` or `document.querySelectorAll`

All of those you can iterate, even though it's a nodeList. If you want full Array support, do `Array.from(YourArray)`